# SVG Skewing without translate-side Effect

Tags: javascript, html, svg, transformation

I'm trying to Skew svg elements inside the javascript with HTML5,
for example:

```
<svg>
<g transform="skewX(20)>
<rect width="50" height="35" fill="red"></rect>
</g>
</svg>
```

The rect inside the `<g>` element is skewed alright,
but the rect element also moved to the right(unwanted), I tried to set the position manually
with transform="translate(-20)" but the measure is not correct,

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

do you mean this?

```
<svg>
<g transform="skewX(20) translate(-20, 0)">
<rect width="50" height="35" fill="red"></rect>
</g>
</svg>
```